# Itextsharp documentation for xml

Tags: pdf-generation, spark-view-engine

I am looking for documentation on the XML parser in ItextSharp, I heard there was a dtd years ago but this seems to be defunt. Does anyone know where I can find out all the valid tags and references?

I am using ItextSharp with Spark

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, [use the source](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/).  Poking around in my copy of the current iText source, I see that the only `SimpleXMLDocHandler` available is `HTMLWorker`.

And if you look at the source for [HtmlTags.cs](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlTags.cs?revision=229&view=markup), you'll see all the tag and attribute constants `HTMLWorker` uses.

It's not exactly comprehensive, but is going to be getting some Enhancement in the immediate future.

---

I don't see a 4.1.2 tag, but there's one for 4.1.6 in the iTextSharp project on SF.  It shows [ITextHandler](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/tags/iTextSharp_4_1_6/iTextSharp/text/xml/ITextHandler.cs?revision=55&view=markup) using a bunch of constants from `ElementTag` in `HandleStartingTags()`.  It also uses [ElementFactory](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/tags/iTextSharp_4_1_6/iTextSharp/text/factories/ElementFactory.cs?revision=55&view=markup) to build the various supported tags.  Looking at the source for each function will tell you which attributes it supports.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I'm actually using the xml parser

  <table width="100%" widths="1;1">
    <row>
      <cell></cell>      
    </row>
  </table> 

where in the source do I find this information?

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: 4.1.2.0, its the version that comes with the Spark View Engine for MVC

Comment: Or run a decompiler on the itextsharp.dll and then search through all the .cs files it creates for the parts you are looking for.